# Scrapy add external library

Tags: scrapy

How can we add external library to Scrapy.I want to add the follwing library to Scrapy:

```
https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapylib
```

How can I add it?

Comment: I downloaded the zip from the location but where do I add that lib to my Scrapy Installation.I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Your github link returns me a HTTP 500 error, I can't help you currently... :(

Comment: Ya Github seems to be down :(

Comment: Hi Maxime the link is up now.

Comment: Have you tried to exec the `setup.py`? It seems a pretty normal package that could be install with `pip`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35978/discussion-between-jeets-and-maxime-lorant)

Comment: I am getting the following message when i do pip install scrapylib:Downloading/unpacking scrapylib 
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scrapylib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why pip can't install scrapylib (I updated pip to version 1.4, but the same issue occurred).

A workaround would be to download a zip of scrapylib directly from Github, extract the zip and then run `python setup.py install`. I was able to install scrapylib and run `import scrapylib` from the Python interpreter without any errors.